# Extra trigger output caused by sample data

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I've used Zapier CLI to create a trigger and it was working great (trigger output looked great, no unwanted fields present). When I submitted the integration to Zapier, they required each trigger to include the `sample` property:

```
perform: perform,
performList: performList,

sample: {
    data: {
        items: [
            {
                item: {
                    id: '42c21e82-0772-4d79-a6b3-c916e51b24ff'
                },
                language: {
                    id: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    //etc..
```

Since adding this, the trigger's output contains duplicated entries- one populated and one empty:

[image: output]

I'm not sure how to get rid of this.. any ideas? **Note:** This occurs in triggers where I *am* and *am not* using `outputFields`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause- the data in `sample` was slightly different from the data output by `performList`.